# Can you recommend a way to secure a server with audit trails?

Tags: security, asp.net

The company I work for has grown from a small business into a business with a multi-million pound turnover.

We have a number of e-commerce sites all built with our bespoke CMS/CRM that has been developed in asp.net. We have had different developers working on the sites at different times and we need a way to secure our server, giving access to certain developers at given times and seeing audit trials of what has been changed.

We have recently been hacked, and one of our developers is today working on securing the server again. But ideally we need a company to manage this for us, to maintain overall security on a top level above all these developers so we are not held to ransom every time something goes wrong. Can anyone recommend a company to help us with this? Our hosting company does not provide this service so we either need a third party to do this for us, or move to a new hosting company that can provide this service.

We are a small team, and although I am computer literature, understanding the complexities of a Microsoft server and how to secure it properly is far beyond my understanding.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't work for ebay by any chance?? ;)  Am looking into it now and will get back when I have something

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of unknowns here, so to answer fully is quite complex.

Are you after application logging or server level logging?  Also, which microsoft OS are you running?  Which version of IIS are you running?

As a good starting off point, i would strongly recommend that you turn on IIS logging.  This can be done by following the [instructions in this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc754631%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).  This will allow you to track access to your sites and its a good place to start.

If you can be more specific about what aspects of your site you are looking to log, we can suggest further.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes thanks for your advice but I'm really looking for someone to do this for me. A reputable company that provides this service. Any ideas?